# @Html.CheckBoxListFor, setting the tab index for each checkbox?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, strongly-typed-view

3rd Party Component: [MvcCheckBoxList](https://github.com/mikhail-tsennykh/MvcCheckBoxList)

I have this strongly typed lists of check-boxes, I just want to set their tab index. How can i do this?

```
   @Html.CheckBoxListFor(model=>model.agentTypeViewModel.PostedAgentTypes.AgentTypeId,
                                                          model=>model.agentTypeViewModel.AvailableAgentTypes,
                                                          agent=>agent.Id,
                                                          agent=>agent.Name,
                                                          model=>model.agentTypeViewModel.SelectedAgentTypes,
                                                          Position.Vertical)
```

I was successfully able to set my other controls tab-index, `@Html.TextBoxFor(p=>p.TRU, new {tabindex = 28, id="txtTRU"})` works fine; but apparently if I don't set a tab-index for the check-boxes, pressing tab will directly move cursor to the list of check-boxes, completely ignoring all other 26 fields that come first...

Any suggestions?

Comment: There is no CheckBoxList or CheckBoxListFor in ASP.NET MVC, so you must be using a third party component.. without knowing what you're using specifically, that will be tough to figure out.

Comment: @Erik Your right, completely forgot that I'm using 3rd party. I will update my question. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're using the MvcCheckBoxList component.  According to the documentation (not sure why you didn't bother to read this):

[MvcCheckBoxList](https://github.com/mikhail-tsennykh/MvcCheckBoxList)

You would just do this:

```
@Html.CheckBoxListFor(model => model.agentTypeViewModel.PostedAgentTypes.AgentTypeId,
                      model => model.agentTypeViewModel.AvailableAgentTypes,
                      agent => agent.Id,
                      agent => agent.Name,
                      model => model.agentTypeViewModel.SelectedAgentTypes,
                      Position.Vertical,
                      x => new {tabindex = 28})
```

Comment: i just saw the exact same thing, I had this component in my code for a long time then the request for tab-index came into play; completely forgot it was third party so never knew about the documentation until you brought it up. Thank you!